# PHP pthreads can't kill thread (& timeout realization)

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I have an example code. What it does is visiting pages. I want to make timeout for thread execution and shut it down when it hangs too long. I thought that there is built-in methods to implement that. Also, i've tried to do it by my own with time() function. But there is another problem. At this point  `$workers[$i]->kill();` script hangs and kill() method returns false so i can't shutdown thread by force. What is happening and what am i doing wrong?
Thank you!

```
<?php

/**
* Author: Abu Ashraf Masnun
* URL: http://masnun.me
*/
//define("TMT",3); 

class WorkerThreads extends Thread
{
    private $workerId;

    public function __construct($string)
    {
        $this->command_string = trim($string);
    }

    public function run()
    {

        echo $this->command_string." ".Thread::getCurrentThreadId()."\n";
    //sleep(rand(0, 3));
    $str = "C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\2web\\phantom\\phantomjs.exe C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\2web\\test.js ";

    $url = $this->command_string;
    $d = explode("://",$url);
    $ex_str = $str." ".$url." > ".$d[1].".html";
    //$ex_str = $str." ".$url;
    //echo $ex_str;
    //$ex_str =  escapeshellarg($ex_str);
    //echo $ex_str; 

    exec($ex_str, $out);

    //print_r($out);
    }
}

//$data = file('sites.txt'); 
$data_f = file('sites_x.txt');
print_r($data_f);
$data = array();
$data_size = count($data_f);
for($i = 0;$i<$data_size;$i++)
{
  $info = explode(";",trim($data_f[$i]));
  if($info[1] === 'y')
    continue;
  $data[] = $info[0];
}
print_r($data);
$data_size = count($data);
// Worker pool
$workers = [];
$t_count = 4;
$flag = 1;
$k = 0;
//echo "$data_size";

while($flag === 1)
{   


  /*
  //echo "$k\n";
  if($k >= $data_size)
  { 
    //echo "111"; exit();
    $flag = 0;
    break 2;
  }
  */
  $c_w = count($workers);

  if($c_w < $t_count)
  {
    for($i = $c_w; $i<$t_count - $c_w;$i++)
    {
      if($k >= $data_size)
      {
        $flag = 0;
        break;
      } 

      $workers[$i] = new WorkerThreads($data[$k]);
      //echo $data[$k]."\n";
      echo "worker $i started\n";
      $workers[$i]->start();
      $k++; 
    }

  }

  $c_w = count($workers);
  for($i=0;$i<$c_w;$i++)
  {

      $workers[$i]->kill();
      unset($workers[$i]);
      echo "unset $i\n";
      //var_dump($workers[$i]->isTerminated(), $workers[$i]->getTerminationInfo());
      /*
      if($workers[$i]->join())
      {
        //var_dump($workers[$i]->isTerminated(), $my->getTerminationInfo());
        echo "joining $i\n";
        unset($workers[$i]);

      } 
      */
  }


}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today with pthreads 2.0.10.

After recompiling PHP from source to get ZTS support, I tried building pthreads (phpize, configure, make).  Everything seemed OK until I ran `make test`. `killed-info` test failed after a 30 second timeout.

Solution for me was to compile the latest pthreads from the [master branch on github](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads).